# Flutter: there is a loading delay between every image on carousel slider only when it is a firebase storage image

Tags: flutter, firebase, image, delay, loading

When swiping left and right the image always has a loading delay even when I go back to view the same image. What I don't understand is why it happens only for firebase images, it's all fine when it is a google image url. And yes, I have used cachedNetworkImage.

```
class ImagePreview extends StatelessWidget {
  final CarouselController controller;
  final ListingModel listing;
  final int activeImageIndex;
  final Function(int) updateActiveImageIndex;
  final Size size;
  const ImagePreview({
    required this.updateActiveImageIndex,
    required this.activeImageIndex,
    required this.controller,
    required this.listing,
    required this.size,
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        CarouselSlider.builder(
          carouselController: controller,
          options: CarouselOptions(
            scrollPhysics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(),
            aspectRatio: 16 / 10,
            enableInfiniteScroll: true,
            viewportFraction: 1,
            onPageChanged: (index, reason) => updateActiveImageIndex(index),
          ),
          itemCount: listing.pictures.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index, realIndex) {
            print('test');
            return GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                showDialog(
                  context: context,
                  builder: (context) => Stack(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    children: [
                      SizedBox(
                        width: size.width * 0.9,
                        child: ClipRRect(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                          child: GestureDetector(
                            onTap: () {
                              Navigator.of(context).pop();
                            },
                            child: Image.network(
                              listing.pictures[index],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              },
              child: SizedBox(
                width: double.infinity,
                child: CachedNetworkImage(
                  imageUrl: listing.pictures[index],
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
        if (listing.pictures.length > 1)
          Positioned(
            bottom: 50,
            left: 0,
            right: 0,
            child: Center(
              child: AnimatedSmoothIndicator(
                onDotClicked: (index) => controller.animateToPage(index),
                activeIndex: activeImageIndex,
                count: listing.pictures.length,
                effect: ExpandingDotsEffect(
                  activeDotColor: themeClass.lightGreenColor,
                  dotColor: themeClass.disabledColor,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the list of images if you want to use the exact same images.

```
List<String> convertedImages = [
      'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/service-finder-27584.appspot.com/o/listing_images%2FhlOvcqhyhyW8UnY1befzM5gKksb2%2F0.jpg?alt=media&token=b6f20bf4-cdb3-4ad4-a983-b16c814a974d',
      'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/service-finder-27584.appspot.com/o/listing_images%2FhlOvcqhyhyW8UnY1befzM5gKksb2%2F1.jpg?alt=media&token=0cddf744-c139-4b04-ba39-b4a7cb7ba044',
      'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/service-finder-27584.appspot.com/o/listing_images%2FhlOvcqhyhyW8UnY1befzM5gKksb2%2F3.jpg?alt=media&token=d361e883-32ee-46db-a5f7-2a2667cd1f98',
    ];
```

i am expecting for the image to load only once and that is it, but it loads every single time i view the image even when i swipe to the next image the first one reloads with a slight delay when i get back to it.

i have made a list of urls of images from google instead of the images i got from firebase and that worked absolutely